# User input to create D3 pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying the create a pie chart using d3pie.js user input values. Below is my code that is functional but takes random numbers on button click.

But I wan't the new segment value to be taken from user input field. I tried assigning the jquery function to a variable and then assigning that variable to value like below but that didn't work. I also tried to directly define the Jquery function to define value.

**Attempt 1 (Didn't work):**

```
var a = $("#first").val();
var num = 4;

$("#addData").on("click", function() {

adata.push({
  label: num.toString(),
  value: a
});

pie.updateProp("data.content", adata);
num++;
```

**Attempt 2 (Didn't work):**

```
adata.push({
label: num.toString(),
value: $("#first").val()
});
```

Below is my working code, would really appreciate some inputs from the folks on this.

```
var adata = [
        {
            "label": "JavaScript",
            "value": 5,         
        },
        {
            "label": "Ruby",
            "value": 3,             
        },
        {
            "label": "Java",
            "value": 2,             
        }   
    ];
--------------------
"data": {
    "sortOrder": "value-desc",
    "content": adata
--------------------
var num = 4;
$("#addData").on("click", function() {
adata.push({
  label: num.toString(),
  value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
});
pie.updateProp("data.content", adata);
num++;

--------------------
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="first">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addData">Add Value</button>
```

Comment: @Cyril, It actually gets auto refreshed as in case of using Math.random. I'm stuck in assigning the input value to the object "value" here. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because you are passing a string in `value`, it expects a number.

in your code

```
adata.push({
  label: num.toString(),
  value: a //incorrect it has to be a number.
});
```

need to do

```
 adata.push({
  label: num.toString(),
  value: +$("#first").val() //make it a number so + is appended.
});
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ab2FuF1ceYDxttp1NvLc?p=preview)